# how to create file pdf based list data in table

Tags: php, mysql, web, localhost, pdf-generation

i must create form php using web program and local database(PhpMyAdmin)
but i dont know how to create multiple field so i search some code and i found this code, i dont know how create list from this, please someone help me
i have 7 days left..

i use fpdf library to make pdf, but if you suggest other, im really appreciate it
[link fpdf](http://www.fpdf.org/)

i need to display name in format this
example:

1. name / Id.122443
2. name /Id.1223

this is code i used

```
<?php
//Database connection file
include('connection.php');

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
// Counting No fo skilss
$count = count($_POST["skill"]);
//Getting post values
$skill=$_POST["skill"]; 
if($count > 1)
{
    for($i=0; $i<$count; $i++)
    {
        if(trim($_POST["skill"][$i] != ''))
        {
        $sql =mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO tblskills(skill) VALUES('$skill[$i]')");
        }
    }
echo "<script>alert('Skills inserted successfully');</script>";
}
else
{
echo "<script>alert('Please enter skill');</script>";
}
}
?>
<html>
    <head>
<title>PHPGurukul Programmin Blog | Dynamically Add or Remove input fields in PHP with JQuery</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="container">
    <h2 align="center">Dynamically Add or Remove input fields in PHP with JQuery</h2><br />
    <div class="form-group">
<form name="add_name" id="add_name" method="post">
<div class="table-responsive">
<table class="table table-bordered" id="dynamic_field">
<tr>
<td><input type="text" name="skill[]" placeholder="Enter your Skill" class="form-control name_list" /></td>
<td><button type="button" name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-success">Add More</button></td>
</tr>
</table>
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Submit" />
</div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var i=1;
    $('#add').click(function(){
    i++;
    $('#dynamic_field').append('<tr id="row'+i+'"><td><input type="text" name="skill[]" placeholder="Enter your Skill" class="form-control name_list" /></td><td><button type="button" name="remove" id="'+i+'" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove">X</button></td></tr>');
    });
    
$(document).on('click', '.btn_remove', function(){
var button_id = $(this).attr("id"); 
$('#row'+button_id+'').remove();
    });
});
</script>
</html>
```

connection.php

```
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","test");
?>
```

name database "test" and this is for make table

```
CREATE TABLE `tblskills` ( `id` int(11) NOT NULL `skill` varchar(250) NOT NULL) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

i wish this can make pdf file can display list name,
example :

1.name /id.1992

2.name /id.1223